gnupg on ubuntu: Getting "No pinentry" from gpg --full-generate-key
I'm a bit of a GPG n00b so please bear with me.
I built gnupg-2.4.5 on an Ubuntu instance and am trying to build a key with it just to test it.  But it keeps telling me that there's no pinentry.  But there is.
When I run
gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg --full-generate-key

it prompts me for the usual things:
What kind of key?  rsa
What size?  3072
How long should it be valid?  0
Key does not expire at all?  y
Real name:  xyz
Email address:  xyz@xyz.com
Comment:  xyz
You selected this USER-ID:
"xyz (xyz xyz) xyz@xyz.com"
Change (N)ame ... (O)kay / (Q)uit:  O
Then it produces this:
We need to generate a lot of random bytes.  It is a good idea to perform
some other action (typ on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg:  agent_genkey failed: No pinentry
Key generation failed: No pinentry

I used this command to configure before I ran make:
./configure --with-agent-pgm="/opt/python/gpg-agent" --with-pinentry-pgm="/opt/python/pinentry" CCFLAGS="-static"

Make seemed to run without any errors and I saw a lot of references to /opt/python/pinentry go by
I know /opt/python/pinentry is there because if I do an ls -l on /opt/python/pinentry* I get:
lrwxrwxrwx 1 vboxuser vboxuser 12 Apr 22 14:50 /opt/python/pinentry -> pinentry-tty
-rwxrwxr-x 1 vboxuser vboxuser 2194176 Apr 22 14:27 /opt/python/pinentry-tty

Any thoughts on how to get past this problem are very appreciated.
Thanks.

For future reference, I found the solution to my problem, although it may not be the solution to everyone's problem with pinentry.  I am using this within an AWS lambda function so I don't care about pinentry because I'm pulling the passphrase out of the Secrets Manager.
So, if I add --pinentry-mode loopback to my call, the error goes away.
